# Getting script file not found issue when running pyinstaller docker command for windows exe in linux machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, docker, pyinstaller

I am building dynamic exe inside docker using [cdrx/docker-pyinstaller (https://github.com/cdrx/docker-pyinstaller) on linux based docker container using below command

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd):/src/" -v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" cdrx/pyinstaller-windows "pip install pyinstaller==5.10.0 && pyinstaller -F script.py""
```

I am getting the below error when i am running the docker run command inside docker to prepare exe file using `script.py` file. I have already created `script.spec` file earlier.

the error I am getting as below

```
395 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.10.0
395 INFO: Python: 3.7.5
395 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
396 INFO: wrote Z:\src\script.spec
402 INFO: UPX is not available.
script 'Z:\src\script.py' not found
```

This is my file directory where i have .spec file script.py file and requirements.txt file as well.

```
# output of ls command
__init__.py  script.py  script.spec
```

this is `script.spec` file content

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['script.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='script',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

Please share your thoughts. Thanks in advance.